# Should Stata recursively search user-added adopath directories?

Tags: stata

I use Stata 14.1 on Windows 8.1 and moved my personal .ado files to GitHub repositories. This put foo.ado in "C:/Users/Richard/Documents/GitHub/foo/", bar.ado in "C:/Users/Richard/Documents/GitHub/bar/", and so on.

I added the GitHub root directory to `adopath` with `adopath + "C:/Users/Richard/Documents/GitHub/"`, but Stata did not search "foo", "bar", and other sub-directories for .ado files. I fixed this by adding the foo.ado repository with `adopath + "C:/Users/Richard/Documents/GitHub/foo"`, and so on.

I expected Stata to search "C:/Users/Richard/Documents/GitHub/" recursively because it does so for `BASE`, `SITE`, and `PLUS`. Is recursive searching limited to the default `adopath` directories?

To be fair, it isn't difficult to add a ten directories to `adopath`, but I want to follow best practices. I can't find much about `adopath` other  than `help adopath` and this [1996 FAQ](http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/programming/search-path-for-ado-files/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stata doesn't exactly recursively search BASE, SITE, and PLUS. It searches each directory, and within the directory, will search in exactly one subdirectory having as its name the first letter of the command being searched for.

Within PERSONAL, I created the subdirectory `f` and placed within it `foo.ado`. When I typed the command `foo` into Stata's Command window, Stata found `foo.ado` and ran the program within.

This doesn't directly solve your problem, but it does show that Stat treats PERSONAL consistently with the other directories, reducing the likelihood of convincing StataCorp to implement your suggestion, but confirming that your workaround seems to be "best practices" such as they are.

On my Mac, I renamed the directory `f` to `gnxl` and then, in a terminal window

```
cd ~/Library/Application Support/Stata/ado/personal
ln -s gnxl/foo.ado .
```

after which, having exited and relaunched Stata, the `foo` command performed as expected. Perhaps this points a direction for you, with some automation to generate the symbolic links as new ado files are created in your repository. I don't know enough GitHub to know if that is possible within its framework.

Comment: Perfectly clear! And actually contained in the linked FAQ. I just needed to reread as Stata suggests. "Read on and the examples will highlight everything for you. Afterward, read the above again, and it should make more sense."